# Find Links and Remove them from HTML

Tags: php, regex

How can I look for links in HTML and remove them?

```
$html = '<p><a href="javascript:doThis('Test Title 1')">Test Title 1</a></p>';
$html .= '<p><a href="javascript:doThis('Test Title 2')">Test Title 2</a></p>';
$html .= '<p><a href="javascript:doThis('Test Title 3')">Test Title 3</a></p>';

$match = '<a href="javascript:doThis('Test Title 2')">';
```

I want to remove the anchor but display the text. see below.

[Test Title 1](http://link)

Test Title 2

[Test Title 3](http://link)

I've never used Regular Expressions before, but maybe i can avoid it also. Let me know if im not clear.

Thanks

Mark

EDIT: its not a client side thing. I cant use javascript for this. I have a custom CMS and want to edit HTML stored in a Database.

Comment: If you use regex for parsing HTML bobince will hunt you down (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: wow. I just read that last week too. Whooops. haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could see if [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

You may try the simplest thing:

```
echo strip_tags($html, '<p>');
```

This strips all tags except <p>

If you really like regexp:

```
echo preg_replace('=</?a(\s[^>]*)?>=ims', '', $html);
```

EDIT:

Delete a - tag AND surrounding tags (code gets messy and doesn't work with broken (X)HTML):

```
echo preg_replace('=<([a-z]+)[^>]*>\s*<a(\s[^>]*)?>(.*?)</a>\s*</\\1>=ims', '$3', $html);
```

Howerwer if your problem is that complicated, I recommend that you try [xpath](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.xpath-eval.php).

Comment: That will strip all links, but how can i search for the link using the match variable. So it will remove that link and the closing tag preceeding it.

Answer (score 1):

You might have some joy with Beautiful Soup - http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/ (Python HTML parsing / manipulation API)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can use</strike>

```
var foo = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

to fetch all the link tags. No need for regular expressions here...

EDIT: I'm just learning to read... ;) Go with PHP's DOM or XML abilities. It should be pretty easy using those.

Comment: its not a client side thing. I have a custom CMS and want to edit HTML stored in a Database.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. You should prefer using PHP's DOM or XML abilites instead of RegEx in that case...

Answer (score 0):

`sed -i -e 's/<a.*<\/a>//g' filename.html`

Note that using regular expressions for hacking HTML is a... dubious proposition, but it might just work in practice ;-)

Comment: Just to warn you... you will get voted down for this one by some community members...

Comment: You sure Franz? I keep reading thats its ok to use it, if its a small porition of HTML.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But you can almost certainly always figure out a way to make your RegEx not work...

Comment: "[make regex break]" -- I agree.  That's why I said using regexes for HTML may be a dubious proposition ||| "[downmod for even suggestion it]" -- well, so be it :(  if the HTML is laid out right, which the OP might be in control of, regexes might actually be the best solution: it works and it's easy/fast to hack up.  Not the cleanest, sure, but sometimes you just need something that works on the data you have (and not the data you don't have).

Answer (score 0):

open the HTML file in Microsoft Expression. 
Ctrl+F and then chose replace tag or tag attributes contents
Easy and quick solution 
Thanks 
Shomaail

Comment: no need to close your answer with Thanks, and your username is already displayed.  Also, this question is tagged "regex" which means the user is looking for a regular expression.  Your answer is simple and elegant, so I would consider it useful to people searching, but it's not necessarily within the requirements of the question.