# How to make whitespaces visible in the command line

Tags: bash, whitespace, highlight

I have a very large file, of which I want to inspect the first 100 lines using `head`:

```
head -n100 large.file
```

I'd really like to make whitespaces lik `\t` `\r`,... visible. How can I do this. I did not find an option in `man head`.

Comment: well cat has many options to show non printable characters, so `cat -vET` should show you what you want. Redirect your output to `cat` and see what happens

Comment: it seems that cat does not distinguish between `\r\n` and `\n`,...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with Perl

```
echo 'fooo        bar' | perl -pe 's/( +)/\033[41m$1\033[00m/g'
```

[`\033[41m`](http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting) enables red color and `\033[00m` disables it. [Perl with `-pe`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302025/perl-flags-pe-pi-p-w-d-i-t) works like `sed` and is needed only to put those special sequences around spaces.

To highlight line breaks change the first part of the regular expression to

```
s/([ \n]+)/...rest of the expression
```

Comment: Nice one! Unfortunately this does not highlight line breaks. I tried: `head -n100 large.file | perl -pe 's/(\n+)/\033[41m$1\033[00m/g'`.

Comment: I used the solution by abasu. Anyway, yours is colourful, and abasu only wrote a comment. Maybe one could also try search and replace `\n -> \\n\n`. This would show everything, and could also hightlight `\r`.