# What happens in each of these Perl one-liners?

Tags: regex, perl, command-line-interface

I am trying to understand the perl one liners in cli.
E.g if I need to do a substitution in a file if I do:

```
perl -e 's/eat/read/g' file
```

Nothing happens.

If I do:

```
perl -i -e 's/eat/read/g' file
```

Nothing happens either to the file.

Only if I do:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/eat/read/g' file
```

the substitution inline in the file happens.
If I do

```
perl -n -i -e 's/eat/read/g' file
```

the file becomes empty!

Can someone please explain the differences and what happens in each case?

Comment: I suggest you to read this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302025/perl-flags-pe-pi-p-w-d-i-t

Comment: [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) tells you what each of these do.

Comment: The first does nothing, because none of the flags are set invoking the behavior of feeding the file to your script.  The second does nothing for the same reason.  The third works because you've told Perl to iterate through a file and send output to the file as an in-place edit.  ...and you've told Perl that you always want to output $_ for each line.  The fourth fails because, though you're iterating over the file and doing an in-place edit, you never send any output to the file, so it becomes empty.

Answer (score 8):

[B::Deparse](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Deparse.html) module will show what switches do to your perl code,

```
perl -MO=Deparse -e 's/eat/read/g' file
s/eat/read/g;
```

nothing interesting here, your code executes as it is.

```
perl -MO=Deparse -i -e 's/eat/read/g' file
BEGIN { $^I = ""; }
s/eat/read/g;
```

ok, `-i` changed global variable [`$^I`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for inline editing, but no file is being read, and no loop here.

```
perl -MO=Deparse -p -i -e 's/eat/read/g' file
BEGIN { $^I = ""; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    s/eat/read/g;
}
continue {
    print $_;
}
```

so `-p` adds `while(){}` loop where every line is read, altered by your code, and written again to file (print in `continue{}` block does that)

```
perl -MO=Deparse -n -i -e 's/eat/read/g' file
BEGIN { $^I = ""; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    s/eat/read/g;
}
```

so `-n` doesn't have `continue{}` block with print like `-p` switch, and you have to print manually after `s///` substitution if you want to make desired changes to the file (otherwise nothing is printed and your file ends truncated as you've already noticed).

Answer (score 2):

Excerpt from `perl -h`:

```
Usage: perl [switches] [--] [programfile] [arguments]
  -e program        one line of program (several -e's allowed, omit programfile)
  -i[extension]     edit <> files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
  -n                assume "while (<>) { ... }" loop around program
  -p                assume loop like -n but print line also, like sed
```

When editing a file in place `-i` you also need to print something to the file, either with `-p` or explicitly (using `-n`) `'s/eat/read/; print'`

A common pattern for in place editing is

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/eat/read/g' file
```

Which will modify your file as expected, saving a backup with suffix `.bak`

Comment: But when I use the snippet with `perl -p -e '...'` nothing is printed

Comment: @Jim - Given `file` with content `abc`, `perl -p -e 's/a/X/' file` prints `Xbc`. Double check your file and your commandline.