# Use sed with variable that contains dot

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am trying to replace (for instance) 6.0 by 6.1 in a file, without 640 being replaced by 6.1

I have currently:

```
sed -i "s/$previousName/$newName/" 'myFile'
```

I think that the solution could be in [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), but I don't find the right solution.

**EDIT** both string are inside a variable and the question this is supposed to be a duplicate of doesn't treat this case

Comment: Ok, I read your link and I found `sed -e 's/[]\/$*.^|[]/\\&/g'` What is this, what does it do and where am I supposed to set my variable in this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using an inner `sed`:

```
sed -i "s@$(echo $previousName | sed 's/\./\\./g')@$newName@g" myFile
```

Comment: why not. Let's try this

Comment: Seems to be working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sed -i "s/6\.0/6.1/" 'myFile'
```

The key is to escape the `.` character in the pattern which has special meaning. By default it matches any character (including `0` in `640`), whereas with a `\` in front of it, it only matches a literal `.`.

Since you have the pattern in a variable, you could escape the `.` in it first like this:

```
previousNameE="$(sed -e 's/\./\\./' <<< "$previousName")"
sed -i "s/$previousNameE/$newName/" 'myFile'
```

Comment: Ok, but the content is inside a variable, so I can't manually escape.

Comment: @Sharcoux I updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I think that Leif Ericson solution came a few seconds before, and I like the one liner, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if `perl` is acceptable:

```
perl -i -pe "s/\Q$previousName/$newName/" 'myFile'
```

From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) for `\Q`

> Returns the value of EXPR with all the ASCII non-"word" characters
>   backslashed. (That is, all ASCII characters not matching
>   /[A-Za-z_0-9]/ will be preceded by a backslash in the returned string,
>   regardless of any locale settings.) This is the internal function
>   implementing the \Q escape in double-quoted strings

Another example:

```
$ echo '*.^[}' | perl -pe 's/\Q*.^[}/q($abc$)/e'
$abc$
```

**Further reading:** [Perl flags -pe, -pi, -p, -w, -d, -i, -t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302025/perl-flags-pe-pi-p-w-d-i-t)

Comment: Cool ! What is the Q for ? I could search myself, but I think of potential futur readers

Comment: Can't open perl script "s/\Q1.6.0/1.6.1/": no folder or file of this type

Comment: what does `type perl` return? does this print hello? `perl -e 'print "Hello\n"'`

Comment: perl is hashed (/usr/bin/perl), and yes, I get Hello

Comment: @Sharcoux, oops my mistake, missed `-pe` in solution.. can you try now?

Comment: I think it's ok now, thanks. I'll keep this solution in mind. Seems easier than sed. Would you mind adding a link to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302025/perl-flags-pe-pi-p-w-d-i-t) in your answer, or an explaination of i and pe?

Comment: thanks, easier to link than adding my own explanation.. `perl -i -pe` is equivalent to `sed -i` to put it in simple terms