# How to divide column subsequently by all other columns or divide it by the multiple of all the other columns?

Tags: bash, unix, awk

could anyone help me with following problem:
I have a tab delimited file that doesn’t have the same number of columns in every row. I need to divide the value in first column subsequently by the values in all other columns.  As a result I would like to get the final number to a new file.

example_file.txt

> ```
> 0.0002  0.2    0.2    0.6   
> 0.03    0.3    0.7     
> 0.004   0.1    0.2    0.005   0.3  0.005
> ```

I filled all empty rows with 1, to avoid problem with division by 0:

```
awk '{for(i=NF+1;i<=6;i++)$i="1"}1' < example_file.txt > example_file_filled.txt
```

example_file_filled.txt

> ```
> 0.002   0.2   0.2      0.6    1   1    
> 0.03    0.3   0.7        1    1   1    
> 0.004   0.1   0.2    0.005    0.3 0.005
> ```

Expected output:

output.txt

> ```
> 0.083  
> 0.14  
> 26666.66
> ```

I know that I can:
-   either divide the first column by second column, then take this value and divide by third column etc.
-   or multiply all columns from second column till the last one and use this value to divide the first column

For the first possibility I was trying to use:

```
awk '{$1=$1/$2; $2=""; print $0 }' example_file_filled.txt
```

This divides the first row by the second one and prints as output the result followed by the numbers that were not yet used for division. I tried to loop over it to get it done until there is no second row, but I didn’t manage.

Could anyone suggest a solution? My real file has >100 of columns. I am mostly using bash / unix, but I will be happy to learn also from other approaches.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop to go through the other columns, then divide:

```
awk '{ val = 1; for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) val *= $i; print $1 / val }' file
```

Or just do successive divisions, again with a loop:

```
awk '{ for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) $1 /= $i; print $1 }' file
```

It's up to you how you want to treat the presence of a `0` in any column - you can add an `if` before performing the division if you like.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly. I don't have 0 in any column, so that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`

```
$ cat ip.txt 
0.002  0.2    0.2    0.6   
0.03    0.3    0.7     
0.004   0.1    0.2    0.005   0.3  0.005  

$ perl -lane '$a=$F[0]; $a /= $_ foreach (@F[1..$#F]); print $a' ip.txt 
0.0833333333333333
0.142857142857143
26666.6666666667
```

Limiting decimal points:

```
$ perl -lane '$a=$F[0]; $a /= $_ foreach (@F[1..$#F]); printf "%.3f\n", $a' ip.txt 
0.083
0.143
26666.667
```

See [Perl flags -pe, -pi, -p, -w, -d, -i, -t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302025/perl-flags-pe-pi-p-w-d-i-t) for explanation on `perl` command line options

Comment: Thanks for the perl version! Unfortunately I can accept only one answer.