# What is the use -I option in perl

Tags: perl

In perl program I have found this line `#!/usr/bin/perl -I Directory_name` 
So I searched in net about the option `-I` in perl but i have not find the correct explaination.Can anyone tell me that what is the use of this option?

Comment: Read [Command switches in perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html

Comment: I believe your question is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302025/perl-flags-pe-pi-p-w-d-i-t

Comment: No, I am asking about capital i option. I have seen the link that you have give but i did not get solution from that link.

Comment: @vaishali  Is there a problem with looking at _Perl documentation_ that I linked for you in the first comment?  It's right there.

Comment: sorry now only I have found this. Thank you .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with your question, not the fact that you are just asking a researchable question, but the fact that you specify file_name in:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -I file_name
```

the above is incorrect as -I searches a given directory for packages and you are specifiying a filename. The below switches will work, but each performs a different function.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -i file_name
#!/usr/bin/perl -I DIR
```

There is a difference between `-i` and `-I` in perl.

So short answer:

-i: Modifies your input file in-place (making a backup of the
    original). Handy to modify files without the {copy,
    delete-original, rename} process.

-I: Directories specified by -I are prepended to the search path for modules (@INC )

Source of more detail [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

Answer (score 1):

We can also find the short description of perl command line options using the below command. So there is no necessary to install perldoc.

```
perl --help
```

The above command gives an short description of each options which are may not find in man pages.

Answer (score 0):

`-I` includes a directory to search for packages.  See [perldoc perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

Here is an example, notice that we `use Bar` instead of `use Foo::Bar`:

```
test.pl
Foo/Bar.pm
```

**test.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -I Foo

use warnings;
use strict;

use Bar qw( frobnicate ); # Foo/Bar.pm

my $output =  frobnicate('hello');
print $output . "\n";
```

**Foo/Bar.pm**

```
package Bar;
require Exporter;
@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT_OK = qw(munge frobnicate);  # symbols to export on request
1;

sub munge {
    my ($txt) = @_;
    return join '*', sort split //, $txt;
}

sub frobnicate {
    my ($txt) = @_;
    return join '....', sort split //, $txt;
}
```

**Output**

```
./test.pl
e....h....l....l....o
```